# How to get User creation date in Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm attempting to pull out the Created UTC value from my Orchard project but I keep getting "object is null"

Here is my code

```
IUser loggedOnUser = _orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser;
var userCreatedDate = loggedOnUser.As<CommonPart>().CreatedUtc;
```

When it hits the second line it throws the exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Looking at this [link](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/435304) my code should work fine.

Comment: So is `loggedOnUser` null? Or is `.As<CommonPart>` failing?

Comment: the loggedOnUser is fine but it would seem the .As<CommonPart> would be throwing the exception

Comment: Does it have the CommonPart attached?

Comment: It would seem it doesn't, but what I can do is update the migrations and create a new migration that will just store it instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` content item contains only a `UserPart`. If you need to access created/modified dates, you need to attach a `CommonPart` to it via data migrations, like this:

```
    public int Create() {
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("User", cfg => cfg.WithPart("CommonPart));

        return 1;
    }
```

Just keep in mind that it won't affect existing users automatically - you would have to go through them one by one and hit "Save" for the part to be created.

Comment: Yep I did that, and I ran a query to update all of the null creation dates :), cheers for the help

Comment: @Piotr Szmyd, is the above line tested? I remember there was a cyclic reference issue.

Comment: @MrGenius Yes, I remember that too, but I think it has been fixed already.